# How to use Sonar Runner on selected files?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I want to run Sonar Runner only on some selected files only. I'm using SonarRunner Ant.

My project directory structure is :

```
MyProject
 |
 |-----src
        |-----java
               |-----A
                     |-----B
                     |     |---<files>.java
                     |
                     |-----C
                     |     |---<files>.java
                     |
                     |-----hello.java
```

Now I want to run Sonar Runner only on *hello.java* file.

```
sonar.sources=../../../MyProject/src      // takes the source directory

sonar.sources=../../../MyProject/src/java/A/hello.java    didn't work

sonar.exclusions=**/**/*.java            // excludes all java files

// now I want to include only hello.java file
// didn't find any parameter for inclusion, but tried the following

sonar.inclusions=hello.java             // didn't work
sonar.inclusions=java/A/hello.java      // didn't work
```

[Referred this article](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) for analysis parameters.

One solution which crossed my mind is : exclusion of all the files but the required ones.

But here the structure is just a small part. In real I have more than 250 java files, and want to generate report for, say, 10 files only. Then, by this approach, excluding 240+ files doesn't look a good idea.

Is there anyway to generate sonar report on selected files, other than the mentioned approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for specific files, you might try the same syntax as is listed to explicitly exclude files ([Narrowing the Focus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) - at the bottom)

```
#Absolute Path
To define an absolute path, start the pattern with "file:"

#Exclude all the *.cs files included in /path_to_my_project/myProject/src/generated and its subdirectories
sonar.exclusions=file:/path_to_my_project/myProject/src/generated/**/*.cs

#Exclude all the java classes contained in a src/generated/java directory and its subdirectories
sonar.exclusions=file:**/src/generated/java/**/*.java
```